# Dumping contents of lost memory reported by Valgrind

Tags: memory, valgrind, memory-leaks, dump

When I run `valgrind --leak-check=yes` on a program, a few bytes of lost memory are reported. Is it possible to view the contents of this memory (i.e. dump the data that is stored in it)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that with the last version of Valgrind (3.8.1):

Start your executable activating the gdbserver at startup:

```
valgrind --vgdb-error=0 ....<your program>
```

Then in another window, connect a gdb to Valgrind (following the indications
given by Valgrind).
Then put a breakpoint at a relevant place (e.g. at the end of main)
and use the gdb

```
continue
```

command till the breakpoint is reached.
Then do a leak search from gdb:

```
   monitor leak_check full reachable any
```

Then list the address(es) of the reachable blocks of the relevant loss record nr

```
   monitor block_list <loss_record_nr>
```

You can then use gdb features to examine the memory of the given address(es).
Note also the potentially interesting command "who_points_at"
if you are searching who has kept a pointer to this memory.

Comment: I get "`valgrind: Bad option: --vgdb-error=0`". (valgrind-3.6.1)

Comment: @panzi I think this only works from 3.8.1 above as ppw mentioned. I tried this with valgrind-3.11.0 and there were no problems.