# How to enable leaks in gdb which is debugging a running process?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdb, hp-ux

I am using GDB to debug a running process using #gdb -p . Now I would like to set some break points and want to get leaks information. But I'm getting an error as below.
(gdb) info leaks
Leak detection is not enabled now.

If I try to set heap flags on, I'm getting error as mentioned below.
(gdb) set heap-check leaks on
librtc is not loaded: Either use -leaks command line option, set heap-check before starting the program, or link librtc explicitly

Hence please help me in a way to enable Leaks information.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are on HP-UNIX,
If so try to use HP Wildebeest debugger.

There is a good documentation:

http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5060273&docId=emr_na-c02725289&docLocale=en_US

**Refer PAGE number 8.**

If you want very specific answer to your question:

[Enable memleak option in gdb for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775312/enable-memleak-option-in-gdb-for-linux)